# Catalog price rule with custom attribute not working

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, catalog-price-rules

I'm running 1.9.2.0

I have a product attribute which is a simple yes/no value.  All products either have this set to yes or no.

I'm trying to use this attribute in conjunction with a Catalog Price Rule.

The attribute itself is set to "use for promo rule conditions".

The Catalog Price Rule is a simple percentage discount, if the attribute is set to "yes".  There are no date restrictions and I have checked the customer groups and all the other rule settings

I have saved it and applied it, with the expected "applied successfully" message from Magento.

I have cleared the cache and the index.

When I go to the front end, nothing has changed.

The discount rule works fine when using any other attribute but it simply does nothing when using my custom attribute.

Screenshots...
www.whitehorsebooks.co.uk/one.png 
www.whitehorsebooks.co.uk/two.png 
www.whitehorsebooks.co.uk/three.png

Thanks.

Comment: can you share the rule config? A screen shot would do

Comment: http://www.whitehorsebooks.co.uk/one.png
http://www.whitehorsebooks.co.uk/two.png
http://www.whitehorsebooks.co.uk/three.png

Comment: can you compare configuration of both working & not working attribute under ` catalog > manage attributes`

Comment: Can you share piece of code which you have written for your custom attribute